# Adding fields side by side in word footnote

Tags: c#, wpf, vsto

Hi I am having an issue with my word application. I am trying to add a field side by side in the footnotes. The issue I am having is a merge conflict and I think this is because the range is the same and over writhing the other field. I am trying add them side by side in one line based on the end point of the previous field.

I have tried collapsing the range to the end but I can't get this to work. Any help would be much appreciated as I am newish to using the VSTO tools and tbh I find them not very good.

```
   public static void insertHtmlIntoFootnoteResult (Field field, List<ct> 
        list)
       {     
      for(var c in ct){
           //I am trying to go to the end here
        field.Result.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd); 

        //How do I create a new field and insert it here based of the the 
        //last fields ending position?
        string guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        var filename = Path.GetTempPath() + "temp" + guid + ".html";
        using (StreamWriter s = File.CreateText(filename))
        {
            s.Write("I am test");
            s.Close();
        }                 
        field.Result.InsertFile(filename);

        File.Delete(filename);

       }
    } // _insertHtmlIntoRange
```

Comment: I'm not following where your code is trying to insert a new field? As far as I can tell, the code you show us is writing text to an existing field. Show the code you've tried that's not working and explain HOW it's not working, please? Also, it would help visualize this if you could specify what kind of field(s) you want to insert.

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister..... Yea so that is the issue I am having in a nutshell.... I literally don't know how to create a new field based on the end location of the current one..... Basically given a field how to find the end location of it, create a new one, and then insert it?

Comment: Yes, but could you please tell us what kind of field is already there and what kind you're trying to insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so I found an answer eventually using the blog post by flowers

https://gist.github.com/FlorianWolters/6257233

Done by changing the insertempty() method to insert a  Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldIf field.

Hope this helps for futre people!